# Pytorch on CUDA in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

total beginner here, with a few questions.

My setup:

- GPU: GeForce GTX 1650
- GPU Driver 430.09 (suggested by nvidia homepage)
- Ubuntu 20.04

Goal:

- Make any Pytorch Version run on my GPU

Questions:

1. Can I use Driver 460, if 430.09 is suggested for my GPU, or am I stuck with 430.09?
2. Which CUDA-toolkit will work on my GPU? Pytorch requires 9.1, 9.2, 10.1, 10.2
3. Which of those do I need to perform pytorch on GPU: Cuda-toolkit, Cuda, Nvidia Driver
4. Do I need to install the Cuda-toolkit/Cuda only inside the specific conda environment, or on the "base", or on both?

Thanks in advance